# when i access nginx in container, i got curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, nginx, curl, containers

```
file: nginx.conf(in host machine)

    listen  80;
    server_name www.mytest.fun;
    charset utf-8;
    root /root/www;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:626;
    }

file: nginx.conf(in docker container)

      listen 626;
      server_name 0.0.0.0;

      charset   utf-8;
      root /root/www;
      location /abc {
        default_type text/html;
        return 200 3;
      }
```

the container info:

```
[root@ismile server]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
ffffa10367a4        myenv:1.0.1         "/bin/bash"         10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         0.0.0.0:626->626/tcp   movie
```

When i use `curl 127.0.0.1:626/abc` to access the nginx in container, sometimes i can get a successful result, but sometimes i get the error tip.

Like this:

```
[root@ismile server]# curl 127.0.0.1:626/abc
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
[root@ismile server]# curl 127.0.0.1:626/abc
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
[root@ismile server]# curl 127.0.0.1:626/abc
3
[root@ismile server]# curl 127.0.0.1:626/abc
3
```

Please help me ! I need your help !
Thanks!!!

Finally, forgive me for my poor English

Comment: How are you starting the container?  What's the actual error message you get?  (Please edit the question to include these details as text and not images, and directly in the question and not behind links.)

Comment: Ok, I modified my question, I`m not sure if you can understand me. Anyway, Thanks